# Flatpak bundle libmysqlclient

Tags: vala, meson-build, flatpak, gnome-builder

I'm trying to build a Vala program with flatpak. I need to connect to a mysql-server and thats why i need to bundle `libmysqlclient` with my flatpak.

Thats why I added `mysql_config` to my meson.build file.

```
project('zeiterfassunggtk', ['c', 'vala'],        version: '0.1.0',
  meson_version: '>= 0.40.0',
)

i18n = import('i18n')

mysql_config = find_program('mysql_config')
mysql_vapi = meson.get_compiler('vala').find_library('mysql')
mysql_dep = declare_dependency(c_args: run_command([mysql_config, '--cflags']).stdout().split(),
                               link_args: run_command([mysql_config, '--libs']).stdout().split(),
dependencies: [mysql_vapi])

subdir('data')
subdir('src')
subdir('po')

meson.add_install_script('build-aux/meson/postinstall.py')
```

The problem now ist that mysql_config is not available in the flatpak runtime. So I need to bundle it with my flatpak.

The Flatpak documentation however was not very helpful for me.

[Flatpak Documentation](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/manifests.html)

> Modules
>
> The module list specifies each of the modules that are to be built as
>   part of the build process. One of these modules is the application
>   itself, and other modules are dependencies and libraries that are
>   bundled as part of the Flatpak. While simple applications may only
>   specify one or two modules, and therefore have short modules sections,
>   some applications can bundle numerous modules and therefore have
>   lengthy modules sections.
>
> GNOME Dictionary’s modules section is short, since it just contains
>   the application itself, and looks like:
>
> ```
> "modules": [   {
>     "name": "gnome-dictionary",
>     "sources": [
>       {
>         "type": "archive",
>         "url": "https://download.gnome.org/sources/gnome-dictionary/3.26/gnome-dictionary-3.26.0.tar.xz",
>         "sha256": "387ff8fbb8091448453fd26dcf0b10053601c662e59581097bc0b54ced52e9ef"
>       }
>     ]   } ]
> ```
>
> As can be seen, each listed module has a name (which can be freely
>   assigned) and a list of sources. Each source has a type, and available
>   types include:
>
> ```
>     archive - .tar or .zip archive files
>     git - Git repositories
>     bzr - Bazaar repositories
>     file - local file (these are copied into the source directory)
>     dir - local directory (these are copied into the source directory)
>     script - an array of shell commands (these are put in a shellscript file)
>     shell - an array of shell commands that are run during source extraction
>     patch - a patch (are applied to the source directory)
>     extra-data - data that can be downloaded at install time; this can include archive or package files
> ```
>
> Different properties are available for each source type, which are
>   listed in the Flatpak Builder Command Reference.

Can someone tell me how to add `libmysqlclient` to my flatpak and how to use `mysql_config` to set the correct compiler flags for my flatpak.

This is my manifest (the gnome-builder default):

```
{
    "app-id" : "org.gnome.Zeiterfassunggtk",
    "runtime" : "org.gnome.Platform",
    "runtime-version" : "3.28",
    "sdk" : "org.gnome.Sdk",
    "command" : "zeiterfassunggtk",
    "finish-args" : [
        "--share=network",
        "--share=ipc",
        "--socket=x11",
        "--socket=wayland",
        "--filesystem=xdg-run/dconf",
        "--filesystem=~/.config/dconf:ro",
        "--talk-name=ca.desrt.dconf",
        "--env=DCONF_USER_CONFIG_DIR=.config/dconf"
    ],
    "build-options" : {
        "cflags" : "-O2 -g",
        "cxxflags" : "-O2 -g",
        "env" : {
            "V" : "1"
        }
    },
    "cleanup" : [
        "/include",
        "/lib/pkgconfig",
        "/man",
        "/share/doc",
        "/share/gtk-doc",
        "/share/man",
        "/share/pkgconfig",
        "/share/vala",
        "*.la",
        "*.a"
    ],
    "modules" : [
        {
            "name" : "zeiterfassunggtk",
            "buildsystem" : "meson",
            "config-opts" : [
                "--libdir=lib"
            ],
            "builddir" : true,
            "sources" : [
                {
                    "type" : "git",
                    "url" : "file:///home/g.zehetner/Projekte/ZeiterfassungGtk"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to disable this flatpak nonsense? I already have /usr/include/mysql++/mysql++.h but Eclipse tries to locate this is a flatpak directory with a magic directory name. Since the new Eclipse/LinuxMint20 I can only build from a terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flatpak aims to distribute applications on Linux by using containerization technologies. This allows Flatpak to be independent of current distributions like Ubuntu and Fedora. It seems, however, the person creating a Flatpak needs to develop some of the skills of a distribution packager. Dependencies for a Flatpak are placed in the `modules` section of manifest and these will be built and included in the Flatpak. What follows is untested so some details may be missing, but it aims to give an overview of the ideas to help. There are a few options:

### `libmariadb`

MariaDB is a fork of MySQL. Forked by the community after concerns over Oracle Corporation's acquisition of MySQL. I've listed this first because it seems the easiest option, at least in the longer term.

MariaDB has [releases of `mariadb-connector-c`](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-c/releases) on GitHub. For some reason GitHub doesn't show checksums for these releases. So the [MariaDB Foundation's download section](https://downloads.mariadb.org/connector-c/3.0.6/) is a better option here. `mariadb-connector-c` can connect to both MariaDB and MySQL.

From looking at the source code the build system for `mariadb-connector-c` is CMake. There are options in the [CMakeLists.txt file](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-c/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) like `WITH_SSL` that you may need, but the manifest snippet below ignores the use of `config-opts`. This [Flatpak GitHub issue](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/546) may have a relevant example on how to use `config-opts` for a CMake build.

So we have a source release, a checksum and we know the build system. By adding something like this to the `modules` section of your manifest you should be able to include a build of `mariadb-connector-c` in your Flatpak:

```
{
  "name": "mariadb-connector-c",
  "buildsystem": "cmake",
  "sources": [
    {
      "type": "archive",
      "url": "https://downloads.mariadb.org/f/connector-c-3.0.8/mariadb-connector-c-3.0.8-src.tar.gz",
      "sha256": "2ca368fd79e87e80497a5c9fd18922d8316af8584d87cecb35bd5897cb1efd05"
    }
  ]
}
```

This also misses out the `cleanup` key.

The main problem is getting this to work with your Vala application. The `pkg-config` file is called [`libmariadb.pc`](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-c/blob/master/mariadb_config/libmariadb.pc.in). So your VAPI will need to be renamed to `libmariadb.vapi`. You can copy the `mysql.vapi` from `/usr/share/` to your local application source directory and rename is as `libmariadb.vapi`. You will need to adjust your `meson.build` to include that as a VAPI search directory and you should no longer need to search for `mysql_config`. `pkg-config` will do the job of `mysql_config` instead.

It looks like MySQL C header files remain a part of `maria-connector-c`. Fingers crossed it will just work. There are additional symbols in C headers that are MariaDB specific. If you want to modify the VAPI read [Writing a VAPI Manually](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/LegacyBindings). Please consider submitting your enhancements to the [Vala mainline repository](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala) afterwards.

### `mysqlclient`

MySQL appears to require the download of the server just to build the client. I started with this page, titled [Download Connector/C (libmysqlclient)](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/). This advises the Linux 'Client Utilities Package is available from the MySQL Community Server download page'. The [Download MySQL Community Server page](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) does not mention 'Client Utilities Package' and only allows the download of a 300MiB+ package of the server and C client. That was why I suggested the `libmariadb` option may be the better one in the longer term. There is also a page [MySQL Connector/C (Archived Versions)](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-c/), where the archived version is a 8.7M download. Using the old version may be a better option to start with.

The Flatpak manifest would be similar to the one for `libmariadb`. The [MySQL source is available from GitHub](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server) and also uses CMake.

MySQL 8's [`CMakeLists.txt`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/scripts/CMakeLists.txt) file does show the `pkg-config` file is `mysqlclient.pc`. So the Vala VAPI should really be `mysqlclient.vapi`. Contributions to the Vala repository are welcome to fix this. By using the `pkg-config` name you should no longer need to find `mysql_config` in `meson.build`.

I also did a search of the [Flathub repository](https://github.com/flathub) to see if any other projects were using `mysqlclient` or `libmariadb` in their manifests. Nothing was found.

### The Cardboard and Tape Option

If you want a rough, prototype, solution then Flatpak does provide a `simple` build type. This allows commands to be run, like `cp`. So a quicker option may be to copy your local MySQL client files to the Flatpak. This would at least allow you to progress with development and come back to implementing a robust solution for the final release. See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/1691) and the [LibreOffice Flathub manifest](https://github.com/flathub/org.libreoffice.LibreOffice/blob/master/org.libreoffice.LibreOffice.json) for examples of `simple` builds. Also the Flatpak file structure is documented in [Requirement and Conventions](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak-docs/blob/4fdaf65142ab462fa75e84e45c3df44e8d867f3c/docs/requirements.rst) and in the [typical filesystem inside a Flatpak sandbox](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/wiki/Filesystem).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will try this.